# Do the Herbie Volkswagon red white and blue stripes have any meaning?

Tags: vw, bmw, history

Since we have a [history](/questions/tagged/history) tag I thought I'd ask what the Herbie Vokswagon stripes possibly meant:

[image]

I know like the BMW stripes:

[image]

They have a meaning:

> The three stripes representing the motorsport division have become
>   iconic to the M brand.  Its stripes have been seen on the racing
>   liveries of BMW’s race cars ever since the 1970s.  The three M stripe
>   colors of blue, purple and red were not randomly chosen, their colors
>   have a meaning and a history.
>
> The blue represents the blue taken from the Bavarian flag.  BMW does
>   stand for “Bavarian Motor Werks” after all so it is fitting to have
>   the color of blue from the city where the BMW brand is established. 
>   The third stripe is red which represents a partnership BMW had with
>   Texaco in the early racing days.  The middle color of purple
>   represents the merging of the two companies, if you were to mix the
>   blue and red together you get purple.  This is a simple and elegant
>   way to represent the partnership of the brands.

*taken from [Bimmer Tips](http://bimmertips.com/origin-bmw-motorsport-colors/)*

However when I research the history of Herbie I'm unsure if it's a design preference or if that had meaning per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbie).  So do the stripes from the famous Volkswagon car symbolize anything other than a design preference?

Comment: While I'm not a *Herbie* aficionado, I'd suggest the stripes being red, white, and blue pays homage to the colors of the United States, like so many similar things do.

Comment: I tend to agree with Paulster2, although I can't find any basis for that other than that it came from Disney...

Comment: They are to make the car go faster - commonly known as “go faster stripes” in some countries - often fitted by younger petrol-heads along with furry dice, large loud exhausts etc etc :) :)

Comment: As for red white and blue - it could go back to the French as those are the colours of the french flag and many racing cars have had those stripes - no insults intended here - just a comment so don’t flame me !

Comment: Red, white and blue are also the colours of the UK ;) - but when it comes to racing cars, they were the colours of Czechoslovakia, Luxembourg and Chile - the US used white with blue stripes, UK all-green, and France all-blue. Germany (where VW come from) used all-silver

Comment: @SolarMike - Don't say that to someone from France ... they'll tell you their colors are *bleu, blanc et rouge* ... quite the opposite of R, W, & B.

Comment: @Herbie and there was me thinking BMW stood for Bavarian Miste Wagon - especially considering how they are driven...